# Use smart folder as Finders default folder

Tags: finder, defaults, smart-folders

Does anybody know how to setup a smart folder as Finders default folder?

If I try to select the smart folder in Finder settings, the "choose" button is deactivated like the screenshot shows:

[image: Finder settings]

Answer (score 1):

Finder preferences doesn't allow this. You need to set the preference yourself:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder NewWindowTargetPath -string "file:///Users/path"
```

<sup>Requires log out and log in.</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately not working for me, i tried
`defaults write com.apple.finder NewWindowTargetPath -string "/Users/"`
and a new Finder windows defaults to `/Users/paul` (I restarte the Finder app)

Another question: Since the smart folder ist just a ".savedSearch" file, do I have to point "NewWindowTargetPath" directly to the file?

Comment: I can confirm this does not work

Comment: @mliqu Apologies, I missed the `file://` prefix, can you try again?

Comment: @bassgang Yes, you should be able to point this at a ‘.savedSearch’. I missed the `file://` prefix — see the edit.

Comment: @grgarside thanks for replying, still not working for me, here is what i am doing:
`defaults write com.apple.finder NewWindowTargetPath -string "file://Users/mliqu/Library/Saved Searches/Recent Folders.savedSearch"`

Comment: @mliqu I tried this including the file prefix and it works fine for me, 10.11.4b7. I'm not sure what else to suggest, apologies again.

Comment: @grgarside oh, well, i'm on 10.11.3, hope that is the issue... thanks for trying!

Comment: this not will work because #finder not allow it either - btw for that he use completely different object "/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Resources/MyLibraries/myDocuments.cannedSearch"